# Connecting MPU6050 to Arduino Due but using Jeff Rowbergs Library

Tags: arduino-due, mpu6050, compilation-errors

I am working on a personal project in which I need to collect accurate data from the **MPU6050** using an **Arduino Due**.

I can interface and read data from the MPU using the **SLC and SDA pins** and the "Adafruit Library" or the "MPU6050_Light" library. However I have been told that the [Jeff Rowberg library](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib) combines both accelerometer data and gyroscope data to get a more accurate measurement of roll, yaw, and pitch. Every time I've tried using the library I get the error below:

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Due (Programming Port)"

...

exit status 1

Is there anything I can do to get this to work on the Due's processor (which I know has a different architecture). If not what can I do to get accurate reading on the Due. I should note that the code works perfectly fine on the Uno.

Comment: Turn on verbose mode and see if anything more useful shows in the listing.